# How to get group law of elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}$ by Weierstrass $\wp$-function?

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions, divisors-algebraic-geometry

A elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}:y^2=4x^3+ax+b$ can be associated with a torus over $\mathbb{C}$ by Weierstrass  $\wp$-function, and therefore obtains a group structure. My question is how to prove that if $P,Q,R$ is colinear, then $P+Q+R=0$? I know this can be proved by divisor theory, but hwo to get a direct proof by Weierstrass  $\wp$-function?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by $P$, $Q$ and $R$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_elliptic_function#Addition_theorems which as usual is proven by checking that the RHS minus LHS is a doubly periodic entire function. @M.C. 3 points on $y^2=4x^3+ax+b$.

Comment: An easy way is to use the $3\times 3$ determinant formula [DLMF 23.10.5](https://dlmf.nist.gov/23.10.E5). This is also mentioned in the Wikipedia article on Weierstrass elliptic functions.